# Linux kernel/os source code documentation?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, fedora

Is there a Linux distro (other than Minix) with good documentation for the source code? Or, is there some good documentation to describe the general Linux source code?

I have downloaded the Kernel source code, but, it is (unsurprisingly) a little overwhelming to find my way around and I wondered if there were some higher-level documentation to go with how  the Linux kernel works?

Comment: The code is self documenting. :-)

Comment: MINIX is not a Linux distro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried having a look on [The linux documentation project](http://tldp.org/) I've find it quietly exhaustive regarding linux
They have a section [The Linux Kernel](http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/tlk.html) wich is an online book that explains 
how the linux kernel works and why it does behaves in certain ways, you should deffinitely
look into it because it's very well made.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the Linux kernel code has decent commenting as documentation, but if you're going to be getting into kernel development, I'd recommend picking up a good book. A good, relatively easy-to-read one is [Linux Kernel Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468), by Robert Love. I got started on the Second Edition when I was in college, and keep a copy of the third on my bookshelf now.

I also find the [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.linux.no/) site helpful in jumping around the kernel source code. It's nice for tracking down functions that are in different files, and getting at what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn about operating systems and their basics, I strongly suggest you to start with a small kernel and then ramp up to learn about Linux. Starting with an operating system like Linux would be overwhelming in terms of code and documentation.

There is XV6 operating system which follows the basic Unix notion of files and processes. You can get the code listing and the documentation explaining the code properly. Here is a link to it. [link](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2011/xv6.html).

Since academia is using this course as a baseline, I think you should get good support for understanding the same.

Comment: My second question was going to be, how would the XV6 and Minix OS size compare with a modern Linux distro, number of code lines etc?

Comment: in terms of code size the difference would be huge. modern linux kernel is much more than a bare bone. for example, virtualization solutions like xen, kvm have been built into the mainline kernels .. the basic code (bare bones providing abstractions) would be comparable to a xv6 but a lot of unwanted (from a beginer's perspective) code would overwhelm your learning process.

Comment: are there any "barebone" linux kernals available- i.e just the important stuff (signals, network, files, processes etc)?

Comment: yes there are. micro-kernels are there which perform only critical tasks

Answer (score 0):

[Linux Core Kernel Commentary](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1576104699) is a little dated, but is still an excellent source of info.

Answer (score 0):

For something which is not obsolete (like `kernel.org/doc` is), you may see:

- [Free Electrons Linux/Documentation/ (3.8)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/)
- [Linux Cross Reference kernel/Documentation/](http://www2.comp.ufscar.br/lxr/source/Documentation/)
- [kernel-doc (3.6.10)](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/20044657/dir/fedora_1/com/kernel-doc-3.6.10-4.fc18.noarch.rpm.html)

The first is the one I prefer personally (clean, readable, pleasant, up‑to‑date).

The second is the most well known.

The third, is for download, if you wish to browse and search it off‑line (may be handy in some case).

My two cents as a side note before I leave: I feel it's weird how for such a famous stuff as the Linux kernel is, when you search the web for documentation, you get masses of obsolete documentations, and how the rather up‑to‑date ones seems to be rather hidden and far from the top position of search engines.